# Installing node.js 6.3.1 - no such file or directory

Tags: node.js, linux

I'm trying to install the latest version of node on Elementary OS based on Ubuntu 14.04.

I've purged all other version of node.

I run this command as explained in a few places on the web:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.3.1 | sudo -E bash -
```

Then I get this output:

```
bash: line 1: html: No such file or directory
bash: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
'ash: line 2: `<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: shouldn't this be like on server-fault?

Comment: @Iceman it's for my development environment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use `https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x` as the URL and not `https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.3.1`.

https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.3.1 returns a 404 whereas https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x returns the script you need to run.

Answer (score 2):

i was facing similar problem with following

```sh
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.11.x -o nodesource_setup.sh
```

changed it to following to get it working

```sh
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x -o nodesource_setup.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

## Using Ubuntu

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

And you will get v12.16.3 Latest stable release